# Sublime or Atom- Open all files within a certain folder via sidebar

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

Sometimes I'm looking for a specific piece of code and I know it's in a certain folder but I forget which file I placed it in. It would be nice if I could move my cursor to the sidebar and right click on a folder to open all of the files that reside inside it.  Is there a package/option for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [goto anything](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html) feature in sublime with out needing to search folder by folder.

If the folder is with in your project you can press F12 and type the class name or search for a word that may be on the file and it will show you possible files to go to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds like a useful feature. Not exactly what I was looking for though.